# larger value of two different columns where there are nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm comparing two date columns about bugs, one is resolved bugs and one is closed bugs. I want the larger of the two, but there are null values (when a bug hasnt been resolved or closed yet). How do i take the greater of the two while ignoring nulls values? I saw other solutions, but you have to specify the dates in the code, which i cant do in my data set as its large. the date format is mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss PM/AM

```
(GREATEST(dtResolved , dtClosed))
```

Comment: use `coalesce` on both columns to set a default value.

Comment: @helloworld . . . Dates don't have a "format" (well, under user control).  They are stored in an internal representation.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(dtResolved , dtClosed), COALESCE(dtClosed, dtResolved))
```

Using this logic, if both dates be not `NULL`, then you would get the greater of the two.  If one be `NULL`, then you would get non `NULL` date.

**Edit:**

> the date format is mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss PM/AM

This sounds like you are storing your dates as text, always a bad idea.  To make the above suggestion work, you'll have to convert your text to dates first:

```
STR_TO_DATE('02/28/2014 09:30:05 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %r')
```

Comment: I checked the type of the two columns and they're datetime. sorry i should have worded my question better. so i think your first suggestion should work. as well what would happen if both dates are NULL? would it return null?

Comment: @helloworld Yes, obviously, if two arguments are null the result is also null ;-)

Comment: @KamilG. lol dumb question i know but i just wanted to make sure

Comment: @helloworld What Kamil said; but do you have something in mind for when both dates are `NULL`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to find the average time it takes to resolve/close a bug so if both dates are null, i want to ignore that bug when calculating the average. i think i'm going to add a where clause that states (dtResolved IS NOT NULL AND dtClosed IS NOT NULL) –

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dtResolved, '%m/%d/%Y %r')), 0), COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dtClosed, '%m/%d/%Y %r')), 0))
```

This code will give you the bigger date in timestamp. The reason is that the `GREATEST` function will return your date as a string without any space or slashes between year, month or date. So timestamp is a good way to prevent that.

Just in case `dtResolved` and `dtClosed` are `null` and you would compare them, use `COALESCE` with `0` instead of both value. It will prevent your query from crashes. It will return `0`.

Like Tim told you, converting your string date to date object isn't a bad idea. It is always preferable to work with date object for the multiple function that exist.